# How to get count of two properties in one excel by validating from other excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have two `.xlsx` sheet as shown below. I need to read both of them and do some calculations in python.

**data.xlsx**

```
cola    colb    colc    cold
-------------------------------
 a1   |  test  | PASS  | 1234      
 b2   |  hello | FAIL  | 2345
 c3   |  world | PASS  | 1134
 d4   |  tree  | PASS  | 3321
 e5   |  swer  | FAIL  | 9801
```

**program.xlsx**

```
colf
----
3321
1234
```

Now I need to read `data` and `program` excel and find total count of `PASS` and `FAIL` but for all those `cold` column in `data` excel which are not in `colf` column in `program` excel. Meaning I need to remove rows from `data` excel where `colf` in `program` excel matches with `cold` in `data` excel and then count total of `PASS` and `FAIL`.

So output should be as below. I dont need to count `PASS` and `FAIL` for `3321` and `1234`.

```
PASS - 1
FAIL - 2
```

I was reading more about panda library but not able to understand on how can I do this logic using that? or If there is any better way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
file_name = 'data.xlsx' 
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, index_col=0)
```

**Note:** My excel has large number of rows and also it has some empty rows so need to filter those out as well in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first read excels in `dataframes` using [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', index_col=0)
program = pd.read_excel('program.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

Now, use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True`:

```
In [572]: x = (
     ...:     data.merge(program, left_on="cold", right_on="colf", how="left", indicator=True)
     ...:     .query('_merge == "left_only"')["colc"]
     ...:     .value_counts()
     ...: )
     ...: 

In [571]: print(x)
Out[571]: 
FAIL    2
PASS    1
Name: colc, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What is `In [570]:` and `In [571]`? i am kind confuse. I am relatively new to python so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: I can just print value of x?

Comment: @AndyP `In [570]:` These are just line numbers of my `ipython` terminal where I solved your problem. You can ignore these and copy rest of the code and check if it works.

Comment: so after `x = ...` I can just print x? which will give me count of fail and pass?

Comment: And it will filter out empty rows right in both the sheets? Correct

Comment: Yes, please run the code. You will get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df1[~df1.cold.isin(df2.colf)].colc.value_counts()
```

where `df1` is the dataframe from "data.xlsx" and `df2` from "program.xlsx".

---

Output:

```
FAIL      2
PASS      1
Name: colc, dtype: int64
```